# Why is my props not being received by the component in React router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Header.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch, withRouter, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from "react-router-dom";
...
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/PSli" render={(props) => <PSli text="Hello, " {...props} />} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

PSli.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react"

class PSli extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      timer: true,
      numOfSlides: 4,
      whichSlideActive: 0,
      slideData: {}
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("mounted" + this.props.text)
    this.setState({
      loading: false
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default PSli
```

How come the props isn't being sent from `Header` to `PSli`.

Comment: Should it be `this.props.text`?

Comment: Sorry it's a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: Have you tried to log `this.props`? Besides, do you encapsulate `PSLi` in a HOC that might override the `text` props ?

Comment: are you hitting the route correctly? is it actually rendering this component? did you try changing the prop name to something specifically ridiculous to be sure its not being overridden? Could something else be rendering this component?

Comment: @JohnRuddell Yes i am hitting as the `render` is generating the content. The component only gets invoked by the link in the route.